# List comprehension with single object in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like so,

```
<Node: uuid=c1f462dde9ff6eb80b4197db5972c4feaf29e4e7, name=new-node, state=PENDING, public_ips=[], private_ips=['10.0.2.217'], provider=Amazon EC2 (ap-northeast-1) ...>
```

Node is a single object in the list, and I want to access only the name attribute from the object. I tried this,

```
[i.name for i in my_list]
```

It is showing error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "create.py", line 50, in <module>
name = [i.name for i in sample]
TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable
```

How to fetch only name attribute from this object?

Comment: if `sample` is a Node object, do - `name = sample.name` .

Comment: Your list is not a list, lists start with `[`, not `<`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, you are trying to iterate over something that is not iterable. i.e. you cannot loop over it.

You simply need to access it as `sample.name`